# How to redirect ending URLS?

Tags: .htaccess, url

I'm not quite sure what the terminology is but all I want to do is redirect URL's after mydomain.com like mydomain.com/todays-news.

*How would I point this "todays-news" url to lets say a file within a directory like a portfolio?

Also what do you call this ending url? A sub domain?*

Answer (score 0):

[SEF URL](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)

Add this to your `web_root/.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^todays-news/?$ /portfolio/some_file.php [NC,L]
```

rewriteRule will internally redirect  `example.com/today-news`  to `example.com/portfolio/somefile`